# Illegal Argument exception when creating a bitmap

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
 val sourceBitmap = resizeImageWithAspectRatio(bitmap, scaleImage) ?: return null
    var maxHeight: Int = (scaleImage * .19).roundToInt()
    if(maxHeight == 0) maxHeight = 1
    val resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        maxHeight,
        maxHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
```

I have an error at Bitmap.createBitmap. The logcat shows Illegal Argument Exception. Having a look at stackoverflow the error usually arises when either parameter has value 0, However I have a check in place to see if the value is 0. Anyone knows what the issue might be?

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger?

Comment: Nope, its working fine in my device and emulator, getting a crash report in google play console @LouisWasserman

Comment: Are you certain it's not negative?

Comment: @LouisWasserman scaleImage is the height of the imageview with an image. I believe  that an Imageview cant have negative height? Maybe I'll add that check as well. Any other possible fix?